# How to securely send bank details to someone?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, ubuntu-mate, pgp

I have completed my internship and my employer wants me send him my bank account details so that he can transfer me my stipend. How can I securely do this? I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04. My employer is not that tech savvy.

Comment: What is so secret in your bank details?

Comment: Don't include your PIN. That's about it? And what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: If the employer is not tech savvy I suggest requesting a paper check.

Comment: Isn't it a good practice to not let your bank account number be out there in unencrypted format on the internet?

Comment: This question is better placed at http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not just call the employer? No email records being stored & leaked forever (just whoever is listening to the phone calls...)

Comment: Or use snail mail. No electronic records of the content there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For encrypted messages, you have generally two options:

1. **Public/private (or rather hybrid) cryptosystems**

   OpenPGP belongs to this category, also S/MIME does. The recipient will provide you with a public key, which you use to encrypt the message. The recipient will be able to decrypt it with his private key.

   The advantage is that you do not need to transmit any secret through a separate, secure channel.
2. **Symmetric cryptosystems**

   You and the recipient share a secret, which is used for encryption and decryption of the message. This is used with symmetric OpenPGP encryption, but also with encrypted archives (zip, rar) -- generally, symmetric encryption will be used when you encrypt with a passphrase that both sender and recipient must know.

   The recipient does not need to provide you with a passphrase, but you will have to transfer the secret passphrase through a secure (and authenticated) channel, for example by meeting or calling him. The recipient must have software capable of using the specific protocol, of course.

As the recipient is not tech-savvy (and does not have an IT department taking care of this), likely he will not have setup public/private key cryptography. He will likely have some software around that is able to decrypt ZIP archives or office documents, but still you'll have to get the passphrase to him. Before sending encrypted messages, better ask if he's capable of receiving such.

The pragmatic solution: either don't care about sending the account information encrypted (in most legislations you'll just have some trouble in case of fraud,  but not actual loss of money and can reverse malicious bookings easily), or print/write everything on a piece of paper and send him a letter, or request a paycheck. Depending on the amount and whether the company is using it, using a service like PayPal might be an option, but will cost some fees (probably: you).

Comment: I was thinking about encrypting a text file in a rar archive with a password that has 2 parts - one part is a long random phrase and the other is a secret that we share(wifi password). I keep that archive in my dropbox and share my link with him while giving the password(and hint) to him in an encrypted email. As soon as I receive my money, I will delete that rar archive. Although, my employer still might have a local copy of it. Can I use a one time password for that rar archive whose passwords are generated by my machine only?

Comment: Technically, you cannot have one time passwords for an encrypted file without any third party services involved. Anyway, one of the principles in information security is considering who's the attacker. Are you afraid of governments accessing your bank account information? Likely, they can do so, anyway. Are you afraid somebody might have fraudulent access to your employee's network? The (probably decrypted) information will be stored somewhere, anyway (your employer will have to keep track of business letters). Is there really a major issue in just sending the information unencrypted?

Answer (score 1):

If your employer is not tech savvy, the problem is more interesting. You can't assume he can set up PGP or SMIME mail, probably can't open a RAR file.

Since I know almost certainly this employer uses MS Windows (don't all non-savvy people?), I know he has a zip opener in windows explorer. So If I were you, I'd 1) Make a txt file named "bank.txt" with the information in it and 2) create a password protected zip:

```
zip -e bank.zip bank.txt
```

That will ask you for a password twice.

Send that in an email attachment, then phone him up and tell him the password over the phone. If he's really not tech savvy, you need to think of a way to say "please don't give the contents of this file to anybody or post it on your blog" without hurting his feelings.

This is a pretty good security plan because the main danger you have is 1) mail server admins reading your mail and 2) an old copy of this file sits around in the employer's computer forever. You solve 1 and are pretty save on 2, unless the password gets written on a sticky note.

If you think any of this is too tough for him, just phone me up, give me your bank account number, routing address, PIN, and probably your SSN, your date of birth, address, and your mother's maiden name, and I'll be glad to jot it down on the back of an envelope and drive it over to the boss myself :) Just teasing about the last part.